# Saving imfreehand ROIs in a script

Tags: matlab, image-processing, roi

What I need to do is predefine a lot of ROI within MATLAB using `imfreehand` and then put these ROIs into a script. This really isn't that hard as I can name them and just keep drawing. But the thing I'm lost on is how to save these ROIs within a script without having to redefine the ROIS.

Basically how do I save an ROI in a script?

Answer (score 0):

First, you can access the x,y coordinates of any lines you draw.  When you call `imfreehand`, save its handle and use it to access the x,y data in the lines you drew.

```
hf = imfreehand;
% draw line, maybe insert pause here
hl = findobj(hf,'Type','line','Tag','top line');
x = get(hl,'XData');
y = get(hl,'YData');
```

Then you can use `mat2str2 to save the variables as strings that you can put into a script:

```
>> x = 1:10;
>> sprintf('x = %s',mat2str(x))
ans =
x = [1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10]
```

Just copy that into your script.

Comment: That lets me take out the x and y data, but is there an easy way to put this into a script file? I don't want to have the imfreehand in the script as I don't want to have to draw 50 ROI's every time the program is run. This explain it a bit better?

Answer (score 0):

From MATLAB's documentation:

```
figure, imshow('pout.tif');
h = imfreehand;
position = wait(h); %This blocks until finished
```

you can also do

```
pos = getPosition(h) %gets the position
```

I think you are asking though about how to store each set of positions in one variable. For this a cell array is probably the most convenient thing. I hope that helps.